# Undefined error converting XML to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I'm using a [blob](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json) of code to convert xml to json:

```
// Changes XML to JSON
var XmlToJson = function xmlToJson(xml) {
    //console.log('called xmltojson');
    //console.log(xml);
    // Create the return object
    var self = this;
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

module.exports = XmlToJson;
```

Sample XML input:

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>asdf</string>
<string>123</string>
<string>zxcv</string>
<string>qwer</string>
<string>werty</string>
<string>dfgh</string>
<string>rytui</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

Output:

Looking at the object in Chrome Console I see:

```
Object {Arrayofstring: Object}
  ArrayOfString: Object
    @attributes: Object
    string:  Array[7]
      0:  Object
        #text: "123"
      1:  Object
        #text: "456"
```

I'm having problems getting to the `#text` data.  AFAIK, hash is an illegal character in a variable name.  Why is it there?  How do I access the value of these `#text` variables?

I tried variations of:

`console.log(myVariable.string[0]);`

And the variations I tried all result in undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#text`-variables stem from DOM text nodes (nodeType = 3) which have the shorthand type "#text".

In my console, I can do:

```
> var x = {};
< undefined
> x['#text']= 'abcd';
< "abcd"
> x
< Object { #text: "abcd" }
> x['#text']
< "abcd"
```

So in your case (I hope I get the object and it's children right:

```
console.log (objName.Arrayofstring.string[0]['#text'])
```